# How to sqlite3 SELECT by COLUMN value

Tags: sqlite

My SQL db has 2 tables, `uidmap` and `gidmap` each having 2 columns (`UID`,`SID`) and (`GID`,`SID`) respectively

Both the tables have single entry, as of now:

`GID|SID
30000000|S-1-22-2`

`UID|SID
30000000|S-1-22-2`

Here UID/GID are the primary key and SID also has UNIQUE constraint

I need to add entry into the tables , but first need to check if any such entry already exists
The problem I have that in a `for` loop, I need to do `SELECT` from the table where `UID=<some-value>` or `GID=<some-value>`

One way of doing is to first match which table we are querying into then match UID or GID

Is there a way to match the COLUMN values directly instead of names ?

Something of the type:
for table in TABLES:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE '%ID'=<some-value> and SID=<some-value>`

Also have one additional query, whey do following fail:

`SELECT * from gidmap where UID=<some-value>
Error: no such column: UID`

While a "" around UID suppresses the no such column error:

`SELECT * from gidmap where "UID"=30000000`

Comment: Do the UIDs and GIDs have distinct values?

Comment: Nope, they are they are same values, as of now. But could be different too

Comment: Then how would such a query make sense? Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample data and more precise problem statement

Comment: I also posted a question in the end, why does "" around UID suppresses the error ?

Comment: That would be a second, independent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is not possible to refer to a column value without mentioning the colum name.

Anyway, to prevent errors when you're trying to insert the same values again, and if you do not need to update any old rows, you can simply use [INSERT OR IGNORE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with INSERT..OR..IGNORE

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify this issue, is to use [upsert](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html). With it, you don't need to check if you're inserting something that already exists, since this feature will simply update it (or do something innocuous). While this might not be the most efficient approach, it eliminates the problem of having to check if the data already exist before inserting it.

Comment: My sqlite version doesn't seem to have upsert, sqlite3 --version
3.9.2 2015-11-02

Comment: What do you mean with "not efficient"? How could any other lookup be more efficient?

Comment: @CL. I mean in contrast with a simple insert. Moreover, updating with the same data that is already in the database would be an inefficient process.

Comment: @mittal upsert is available starting with version 3.24.0. Your version, 3.9 is somewhat old, being released in 2015, I'd consider upgrading.

Comment: @gregory Even an INSERT with UNIQUE constraints would have to check for old values. And UPSERT also can DO NOTHING.

Comment: @gregory Can't upgrade the package. It is part of huge customized image.

Comment: @CL , after gregory suggested UPSERT, I started exploring INSERT ... VALUE...ON...DO NOTHING. But then realized that my sqlite3 version is old and doesn't support UPSERT

Comment: Is there no way to refer to column by their values and not names ?

Comment: @mittal Did you customize it yourself (in which case you can customize it again), or are you paying somebody else for support (in which case, what are you paying for?)?

Comment: @mittal it is kinda looney, but you could pivot the table (using case stmts) so rows become columns and then reference the renamed rows as columns.